# TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given error

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, abstract-class

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
class Book(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self,title,author):
        self.title=title
        self.author=author   
    @abstractmethod
    def display(): pass
class MyBook(Book):
    def __innit__(self,title,author,price):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.price = price    
    def display(self):
        print("Title: {0}".format(self.title))
        print("Author: {0}".format(self.author))
        print("Price: {0}".format(self.price))
title=input()
author=input()
price=int(input())
new_novel = MyBook(title,author,price)
new_novel.display()
```

encountering error:TypeError: **init**() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
plz give me ideas on how to fix this error

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your second initiator function. replace "**innit**" with "**init**" in the class MyBook.

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError` will go away once the typo `__innit__`  is corrected to `__init__`

One more correction: We should call the parent class's init method instead of declaring `title` & `author` members in the `MyBook` class again. This will give **oops** inheritance benefits as well.

```
Book.__init__(self, title, author)
```

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
class Book(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, title, author):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author   
    @abstractmethod
    def display(): pass
class MyBook(Book):
    def __init__(self, title, author, price):
        Book.__init__(self, title, author)
        self.price = price
    def display(self):
        print("Title: {0}".format(self.title))
        print("Author: {0}".format(self.author))
        print("Price: {0}".format(self.price))
title=input()
author=input()
price=int(input())
new_novel = MyBook(title,author,price)
new_novel.display()
```